# Grouping rows in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have to match an excel field (column name is `Hostname`) from 1st sheet to 2nd sheet. The 2nd sheet is having multiple entries of the same `Hostname` and corresponding `Application names` and I want to get all the enteries of the corresponding `Application Names` from the 2nd sheet mapped to the `Hostname` of the 1st sheet.

How can this be done? I have tried to apply VLOOKUP but that is only giving the corresponding 1st entry only of the `Application Name`.

Please can someone suggest how can I group multiple entries together in excel.

Thanks

Data from 1st sheet looks like

```
Hostname       Application Name

USSLCWINQ0017   
usslclnxd0100   
usslclnxq7058   
usslclnxq0181   
usslclnxs7000   
usslclnxs7004   
usslclnxd8503
```

Data from the 2nd sheet looks like

```
Hostname         Application Name

USSLCWINQ0017   X
usslclnxd0100   Y
usslclnxq7058   Y
usslclnxd0100   A
usslclnxs7000   B
usslclnxs7004   C
usslclnxd8503   D
USSLCWINQ0017   V
usslclnxq0181   R
usslclnxs7004   Z
usslclnxs7004   S
```

Comment: You want to group the data in the same cell?

Comment: No I want the data in different rows.
  `USSLCWINQ0017   X
  USSLCWINQ0017   V
  usslclnxd0100   Y
  usslclnxd0100   A
  usslclnxq7058   Y
  usslclnxs7000   B
  usslclnxd8503   D
  usslclnxq0181   R
  usslclnxs7004   C
  usslclnxs7004   Z
  usslclnxs7004   S`